# Analysis on OData API of SAP Successfactors for Onbording functionality

Tags: odata, sap-fiori

Good Day !

I am a SAP Fiori Techo-Functional Consultant. Recently we have a requirement to build a Fiori Mobile app for Successfactors onboarding functionality by Leveraging our existing Fiori Front end Server.

We have a Successfactors Cloud solution already. After exploring the architecture of SSF we are now able to figure out that Standard OData API s are available( As part of Integration solution offered by SSF).

I have a couple of queries regarding the Onboarding integration(Odata) functionality.

1) What are all the entity sets available for onboarding end to end functionality in the Odata API?

2) Does the the existing OData API of SSF supports end to end fuctionality of Onboarding? Or do we need to use SFAPI(SOAP UI) for some scenarios?

3) Do we have any provision to enhance/extend the existing OData API in SSF?

Any experts can solve my queries.

Also we got to know that a standard native mobile application is available for SSF. Can i know on high level whether it supports onboarding functionality by default?

Answer (score 1):

1) you can find these in the onBoarding documentation / oData Data dictionary in SF or via a support ticket

2) I would go with oData in 90% of the cases. But some SFAPI services support the deletion of records and some oData records don't. For example PerEmail doesn't support deletion via oData

3) You can create custom MDF objects which are accessible only via oData and not via SFAPI.